# Visual Studio- Hiding the Maximize Button in a Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How do I remove the maximize button from a form? I've already disabled it but it still shows up, it just doesn't work. I want a form with only the close and minimize buttons. It's a Windows Form Application and I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: It's a windows form application.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Hiding the maximize button is not possible without you painting your own window frame.

Having it disabled tells the user that he can't maximize the form which is good UX. Hiding it doesn't help because double clicking the title bar will still maximize the window (if you haven't disabled Maximize).

<strike>You can set `FormBorderStyle` set to the `FixedToolWindow` or `SizableToolWindow`, but then the form will not be displayed in the Windows task bar or in the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> window.</strike> *See update below.*

You can hide the entire `ControlBox` which will also remove `Minimize` and `Close` as well as the context menu.

Pick your poison!

---

**Update (12/24/15)**

I decided to revisit the landscape with various options and it seems that:

1. contrary to what [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41(v=vs.110).aspx) says, setting `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedToolWindow/SizableToolWindow` no longer hides the app in task bar or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> window in ***Windows 7*** and up. `ShowInTaskbar` exclusively decides Show/Hide effect in this case (thanks to @pinowthebird for nudging me to take a re-look).
2. Setting `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedDialog` also hides the maximize/minimize buttons and shows up in task bar, although the default icon is now lost (not sure why).
3. Setting `MaximizeBox = False` does NOT hide the buttons, again contrary to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.maximizebox(v=vs.110).aspx). It simply disables it (and maximize functionality via toolbar double click).
4. Setting **both** `MaximizeBox = False` and `MinimizeBox = False` hides them, irrespective of `FormBorderStyle`.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: <code>FormBorderStyle</code> = <code>FixedToolWindow/SizableToolWindow</code>]
[image: <code>FormBorderStyle</code> = <code>FixedDialog</code>]
[image: <code>MaximizeBox = False</code>]
[image: **both** <code>MaximizeBox = False</code> and <code>MinimizeBox = False</code>]

**Conclusion:**

Based on your requirements, you can either opt for 1, 2 or 3. Hope this helps future visitors.

***Disclaimer:*** These tests were done in VS 2015, .Net 4.6 and a brand new WinForm app. The documentation says that these properties were available since .Net 1.1. However, as you can see in the screenshots - take the documentation with a grain of salt! Also the OS plays a vital role in the outcome.

Comment: The `FormBorderStyle` property does not determine whether a form is displayed in the Windows task bar. The property to change that is called `ShowInTaskbar`.

Comment: @pinowthebird: Your comment made me rethink. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 7):

it is simple :) 
do this

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    MaximizeBox = False

End Sub
```

Now, your client can't maximize your form, even if he/she double clicks the title bar of your form.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the properties of `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedToolWindows` or `SizableToolWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the property "MaximiseBox" to be false in the properties window of the form.
The same goes for the minimize box as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you set ControlBox to False, you will lose the Minimize, Maximize, and Close buttons in the upper right corner. The ControlBox is the object housing the Context menu in the upper left of your form.

If you leave ControlBox set to True, you must set **both** Maximize and Minimize to False - this hides both buttons. Without possibly p/invoking Win32, I don't believe your control gets any more granular than that.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without losing the minimize button though?

Comment: No.  Outside of tool windows, Win32 doesn't provide an out-of-the-box way of having a window with a minimize button without a maximize button.  They come and go as a pair.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form4_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize


 If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then

 Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal 

 End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Please add description to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, First Select the Form, go to the properties and Click on Maximize Box , set it to False.It will hide the Maximize Button.

Answer (score 0):

You could also skip using the default buttons by setting form border style to none in the properties which removes all the three buttons then add a customised button say with an icon file or background image(with close related content of your choice from icons8.com).

Answer (score -1):

We can disable the two icon, *minimize* and *maximize*. You will have to set the "minimize and maximize icon as *false* both. If either icon remains true, then all three icon will be display on your form window.

Comment: -1. From OP's question: `I want a form with only the close and minimize buttons`. Your solution is `No, you can't have that`. This is not true according to other answers listed here.